# Can I stop the cookiecutter if my hook fails?

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I'm using [`cookiecutter`](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) to help manage a web template. You can specify a special file `hooks/pre_gen_project.py` that will run before any of the template commands start. If it fails however, cookiecutter keeps going, even if `hooks/pre_gen_project.py` throws an exception! A minimal example would simply be:

```
raise SyntaxError
```

in this file. Is there a way to halt execution once an error has been raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently, cookiecutter ignored errors in the hook scripts.
I've submited [a fix for this that got merged recently](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/pull/549).

So, if you use Cookiecutter >= [1.3.0](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/releases/tag/1.3.0), the project generation will be canceled when the hook script fails. :)